# How to avoid multiple chain of if else

Tags: c

Hi I have a piece of code as below, I want to avoid multiple if else, is there a better approach for this:

```
if(strcmp(somename, "some") == 0)
{
    fun();
}
else if(strcmp(somename,"some1") == 0)
{
    fun();
}
else if(strcmp(somename,"some2") == 0)
{
    fun();
}
else if(strcmp(somename,"some3") == 0)
{
    fun();
}
```

Comment: Please chose C or C++

Comment: there are total 8 if else if conditions

Comment: If you're literally looking for `"some[n]"`, `strstr()` or `strncmp()` for `"some"` and check the following number.

Comment: Are `fun()`'s all the same or they are different, like `fun1()`, `fun2()` etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a pointer to pointer and a loop:

```
const char *ap[] = {"some", "some1", "some2", "some3", NULL};
const char **p = ap;

while (*p) {
    if (strcmp(somename, *p) == 0) {
       fun();
       break;
    }
    p++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a map (ordered or unordered) mapping values for `somename` to `std::function` instances to call.

Comment: This is c++, the question is tagged C

Answer (score -1):

You can try a simple approach using `switch` cases. For example, you can use it like

```
switch(somename) {
    case "some1" :
        fun1();
        break;
    case "some2" :
        fun2();
        break;
    case "some3" :
        fun3();
        break;
    default :
        //some default case
}
```

also you can use `str2int` in `c++11` in case switch does't work with strings well like

```
switch(str2int(somename)) {
    case str2int("some1") :
        fun1();
        break;
    case str2int("some2") :
        fun2();
        break;
    case str2int("some3") :
        fun3();
        break;
    default :
        //some default case
}
```

Comment: This is C++ but the question is C